# how to export existing firefox preferences to WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I would like to export preferences from existing Firefox profile into WebDriver profile. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Following example demonstrates how to use existing profile named **default :**

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("default");
WebDriver driver = = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use already existing Firefox profile instead of temporary Firefox profile using code like this:

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("MyProfile");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

In case you want to create new profile and add some extensions:

```
File profileDir = new File("path/to/top/level/of/profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
File firebug = new File("C:\\FFPlugins\\firebug-1.7.3.xpi");
File xpathChecker = new File("C:\\FFPlugins\\xpath_checker-0.4.4-fx.xpi");
profile.addExtension(firebug);
profile.setPreference("extensions.firebug.currentVersion", "1.7.3");
profile.addExtension(xpathChecker);
profile.setPreference("extensions.xpath_checker.currentVersion", "0.4.4");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Also you can run Firefox with key `-p` to create new profile for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But keeping a static profile in distributed system is hard. I want to get profile preference alone to be exported to new custom firefox profile. Some thing like, properties file if there is one.